# Simulating a crawler on my website

Tags: asp.net, seo, web-crawler

I need to debug my web app which is written by asp.net to find out how it is acting when rendering the content for the crawlers like **Googlebot**. The first thing I found was some online/offline tools but none of them can pass the ***Request.Browser.IsCrawler*** flag.

Then I tried to simulate a handmade request adding the **Googlebot** ***UserAgent*** but still no chance.

Answer (score 0):

I used **Telerik Fidler** and **Chrome** while setting ***User-Agent*** to ***Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)***, including ***_escaped_fragment_*** in the URI and successfully saw the page from crawler perspective.